# why jquery-ui-datepicker accepts invalid values from keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery UI date-picker to get the date with min and max date range value, it's working on selecting the date using the date-picker widget, but it gets invalid values using the keyboard. I want to get the date by keyboard as well as mouse. Please help me to get valid date value or to show an error message of the invalid date value.

[datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOtiW.jpg)

Comment: You can refer a link: http://keith-wood.name/uidatepickervalidation.html

Comment: the datepicker itself does not validate what you type into the textbox, as far as I know. It's just a graphic tool designed for use with the mouse. You would need to write your own validation code for dealing with keyboard input - that input goes directly into the textbox, it does not interact with the datepicker control at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Iam working with a wordpress site and I have created form using contact form 7 plugin , for the date field only Iam using the UI datepicker. And I have followed the steps as by http://keith-wood.name/uidatepickervalidation.html  for validation fields Now the problem is, it shows the error message only on change the field, but the form get submitted with invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code as below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".datePicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: Date.parse("1900-01-01"),
        maxDate: Date.parse("2100-01-01"),
        yearRange: "c-90:c+150"
    });

    $(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
                "date",
                function (value, element) {
                   // Here you can set date range    
                    var minDate = Date.parse("1900-01-01");
                    var maxDate = Date.parse("2100-01-01");
                    var valueEntered = Date.parse(value);

                    if (valueEntered < minDate || valueEntered > maxDate) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(minDate));
                },
                "Please enter a valid date!"
                );
    });
</script>
```